# Is there a source to find complete iOS apps source code for learning?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm learning allot from Apple sample codes and i'm wondering if there are some other sources where I can find complete apps, apps that could be on the appstore (of course its for the learning, not that im going to do this!) where I can peek at their source code?

Comment: Voted to close as asking for off-site resource. Also I very much doubt anyone will have placed their entire code online for people to steal (I know you say it's for learning purposes but people also steal) so I think you are out of luck for whole apps. However you could look on Github for libraries people have written, have a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/21987/top-10-most-useful-ios-libraries-to-know-and-love

Comment: @Popeye I don't agree understand why this is off-topic, I think theres allot of beginners who can benefit from this information. anyway I found a link to such information http://maniacdev.com/2010/06/35-open-source-iphone-app-store-apps-updated-with-10-new-apps

Comment: The reason it is off-topic is for the reason state below for why it has been closed. You shouldn't ask for off site resources because it can attract opinionated answers and spam answers which are just not welcome here. If you are not aware of how stackoverflow works I would recommend reading around before asking anymore questions and would definitely recommend reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380 Good luck with future questions and answers. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than look for complete app code, look at Paul Hegarty's lessons from Stanford University. They are avaialble for free on iTunes U.

Here's a link https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550

Comment: thanks buddy. also, I found something like i founded http://maniacdev.com/2010/06/35-open-source-iphone-app-store-apps-updated-with-10-new-apps @lascort